# Algorithm to delete node from middle in a singly linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I'm reading Cracking the Coding Interview and doing practice problems and I'm stuck on this one:

"Implement an algorithm to delete a node in the middle (i.e., any node but the first and the last node, not necessarily the exact middle) or a singly linked list, given only access to that node.

EXAMPLE Input: the node from the linked list a->b->c->d->e->f Result: nothing is returned, but the new linked list looks like a->b->d->e->f"

```cpp
void solution1(Node* node)
{
    if (node == NULL || node->next == NULL) {
        return;
    } else {
        Node* ptr = node;
        //ptr is the node accessible
        Node* ptr2 = ptr->next;
        ptr->data = ptr2->data;
        ptr->next = ptr2->next;
        delete ptr2;
    }
    cout << "updated list is" << endl;
    display();
}
```

I implemented the function but I want to confirm the complexity. It will be O(1) space and O(1) time complexity right?
Also , if we want to delete the last node , how do we do it using a dummy node?

Comment: please one question per question. Why would it be anything different from `O(1)` ? There are no loops, no other functions called (other than `display`, I assume that is actually `O(N)`)

Comment: This will not work for the last list node. Further, it defeats the purpose of using a dynamic node link paradigm. Ideally delete a node by pruning it from the list, setting the pointer *within the list* that referred to it (e.g. some node's `next` pointer or the list `head` pointer) to the about-to-be-deleted node's `next` member value. At that time you can delete the now-orphaned node and be done. In short, ideally the only members futzed with during list management ops like this are the head pointer or the `next` members within the list; *nothing else*....

Comment: ...but you cannot do that with the limited data you're provided. e.g. a by-value node pointer somewhere in the middle. you have no way to acquire the `next` (or `head`) that points to the node in question, and thus are severely limited in what you can do. Short version: cruel task, but maybe you'll get something out of it.

Comment: Note that this is **bad C++ design**. The problem is in the `ptr->data=ptr2->data;` line, which fails to consider exception safety. It seems you'd want `std::move_if_noexcept` there. That doesn't mean it's a bad question in an algorithms introduction class - you've got to start learning somewhere. But for production code, stick with `std::forward_list<T>`

Comment: @msalters it probably is (but we lack the code) a struct with two pointers, so no need to move anything. Not deleting the data may or may not be a bug. The names of the variables and even more importantly, the function, are... in the need of improvement.

Comment: @SR_: If `data` was a (raw) pointer, the old `ptr->data` would be leaked.

Comment: Yes, that is one of my points.

Comment: @MSalters for all we know it's `struct node { int data; node * next; };`

Answer (score 0):

Actually it depends on space and time complexity of `display()` but if you don't consider that then yes it will be O(1) space and O(1) time. Simply deleting the last node using `delete node` will make the `next` pointer of previous node a dangling pointer so you can't delete the last node without the pointer to previous node( or `head` pointer of linkedlist).

Answer (score 0):

Yes time and space complexity of this deletion algorithm is O(1).

To determine dummy node you can create a dummy flag by yourself:

```
Node* dummy_flag = new Node();
...

if (node == nullptr || node->next == dummy_flag) {
    return;
}

if (node->next == nullptr) { // if last node
    node->next = dummy_flag;
} else {
    Node* next_node = node->next;
    node->data = next_node->data;
    node->next = next_node->next;
    delete next_node;
}
```

Now if your node->next == dummy_flag then node is dummy.

Comment: also I suggest you to use nullptr instead NULL